# I want to get documents IDs from specific collection in firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have flutter app with firebase firestore in firestore I have on collection inside the collection there is few documents I want to get these documents IDs and put them in list<Strings> to use them in listview.seperated so I can click on one Item and move to another page where I can find the fields of specefic documents but I can't achieve that is there anyway to do that thanks

[image]

I try every thing to get the documents Id but nothing work with me I am new to flutter and firebase please help thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `doc.id` to get ID of document:

```
List<String> iDs = [];
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('buying2')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc.id); //this is document ID
            iDs.add(doc.id);
        });
    });
```